# Hotmail is rejecting email from a digital ocean droplet

Tags: email, email-server, spam

I have setup my site on Digital Ocean and point the Domain name "A" record to the Droplet IP.

Emails sent by the site are being received in Gmail and other email clients ( SPAM Folder ) but it does not reach at all to outlook.com / hotmail.com email address.

I understand that i have only changed the "A" and "WWW" record of the domain name and now i am sending emails from the droplet, which is somehow not right. What configuration i need to do on the server so the emails sent from my server are trust worthy.

**Header of a test email received in Gmail.**

```
Delivered-To: gtemailtesting@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.105.41 with SMTP id gj9csp336738obb;
        Thu, 26 May 2016 01:55:41 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.192.10 with SMTP id hc10mr8173424wjc.71.1464252941808;
        Thu, 26 May 2016 01:55:41 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <register@riyali.com>
Received: from riyal.com ([46.101.217.71])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id wp4si16915971wjb.173.2016.05.26.01.55.41
        for <gtemailtesting@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 26 May 2016 01:55:41 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 46.101.217.71 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of register@riyali.com) client-ip=46.101.217.71;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 46.101.217.71 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of register@riyali.com) smtp.mailfrom=register@riyali.com
Received: by riyal.com (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id D27361408BB; Thu, 26 May 2016 04:55:40 -0400 (EDT)
To: gtemailtesting@gmail.com
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal
Sender: register@riyali.com
From: register@riyali.com
Message-Id: <20160526085540.D27361408BB@riyal.com>
Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 04:55:40 -0400 (EDT)

this is a test message
```

**Server Log ( when sent to hotmail):**

```
May 26 05:16:38 riyali postfix/pickup[30639]: E1A1B1408BB: uid=1000 from=<register@riyali.com>
May 26 05:16:38 riyali postfix/cleanup[31632]: E1A1B1408BB: message-id=<20160526091638.E1A1B1408BB@riyal.com>
May 26 05:16:38 riyali postfix/qmgr[31707]: E1A1B1408BB: from=<register@riyali.com>, size=478, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 26 05:16:40 riyali postfix/smtp[31634]: E1A1B1408BB: to=<xxx@outlook.com>, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.02/0.01/0.53/0.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <20160526091638.E1A1B1408BB@riyal.com> Queued mail for delivery)
May 26 05:16:40 riyali postfix/qmgr[31707]: E1A1B1408BB: removed
```

**Server Log ( when sent to gmail ):**

```
May 26 05:25:33 riyali postfix/pickup[30639]: 7D8B91408BB: uid=1000 from=<register@riyali.com>
May 26 05:25:33 riyali postfix/cleanup[31719]: 7D8B91408BB: message-id=<20160526092533.7D8B91408BB@riyal.com>
May 26 05:25:33 riyali postfix/qmgr[31707]: 7D8B91408BB: from=<register@riyali.com>, size=471, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 26 05:25:34 riyali postfix/smtp[31721]: 7D8B91408BB: to=<gtemailtesting@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.65.27]:25, delay=0.84, delays=0.02/0.01/0.35/0.46, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1464254734 ad7si17051750wjc.239 - gsmtp)
May 26 05:25:34 riyali postfix/qmgr[31707]: 7D8B91408BB: removed
```

Comment: What happened to the messages sent to hotmail?

Comment: It never reached. not in SPAM or inbox.

Comment: Hmm. That email has not been rejected, it has been "queued". This has a special meaning; it means your mail has not been delivered to its final destination, and the mail server will have to deliver it onward later. Wait five days to see if the mail shows up; if it doesn't, then complain to Hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

You SPF Record is being recorded as neutral, these means that you most likely don't have your SPF set up, which you can see here: [Your SPF Record](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/spf/riyali.com/). You can use this [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/) to create one. But I think all you need your SPF record to say is.

```
v=spf1 mx ~all
```

This might not solve your problem, but it puts you on the right path. You're also not signed up for Hotmail's Junkmail filter program `nobl.junkemailfilter.com1` , as I can see you're not [whitelisted](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/blacklist/wl/mail.sedco.com/) when scanning for it. You can sign up here [Microsoft's SNDS program](http://postmaster.live.com/snds/) - Click the Junk Mail Filter program on the left.

You might have other issues, which I can't see I think your rDNS is set up correctly, but you should send an email to `mailtes@unlocktheinbox.com` to confirm.

A lot of times an IP can be on an internal blacklist, I think Hotmail uses [Symantec](http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/), but I scanned your IP their and nothing showed up. But that doesn't mean you are on their internal blacklist. I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Use this, with the server IP in the appropriate place. Change soft fail ~ to hard fail - at some point once this is tested : v=spf1 ip4:SERVER_IP_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE a mx ~all